# How to locate this element on selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]
I don't how to locate this element on selenium

I can't find the `ID` or the `NAME` to locate this object
please help me out!

I tried to find the name or the id but it didn't work out.
I am bad at using `xpath`

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample, inside the quotes put some part of your href text
**//a[contains(@href,'')]**

Comment: Doesn't work.. Is there an alternative?